# Why is the post not coming through on a PHP form Post

Tags: php, forms, post

Ok so this is kind of got me stumped. I have two installs of a shopping cart on my server

[First](http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/t/index.php?route=account/login) and [Second](http://royaltyfreesoundbank.com/jgsnmuegvuzebazfoz/index.php?route=account/login)

as you can see on the top of both pages I am debugging using print_r

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST, true)."</pre>";
```

and its blank on both. If you enter anything into the (Returning Customer) email and password field for the first link you can see the $_POST array with the data you entered..that works great. But on the second form which has the same code other then the styling difference nothing appears in the $POST.

why does one page work and not the other...is there something in the source that i am missing..

Comment: View the headers - is the POST body present? Are there any redirects?

Comment: it should be the same view logic and i dont see any redirects

Comment: @Tamer *should* be is often where you *should* have checked the headers :P

Comment: your array is retuning data on both links for me -- i am using FF 4.0 -- what browser are you testing on?

Comment: ok so it chrome it works fine but in firefox 4.0.1 on the mac it doesnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second example, there are two forms with `id="login"`. One is at the top of the page, and one in the middle of the page. The submit is done by a `$(#login"").submit();` call on the button, which will select the first form with `id="login"`. Since ids are supposed to be unique, try using different ids for each form. Or use something like `$(this).closest('form').submit();`

Comment: You're welcome. I found this by typing `$('#login');` into the Chrome developer console - which will show you the element that jQuery is seeing. You can then mouse-over the returned element, and it will highlight the selected element in the browser. I find this feature very very useful :)